# how to get a raspberry pi to autologin via SLiM at boot?

Tags: raspbian, boot, lxde

I've followed instructions from eLinux ([here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Debian_Auto_Login)) on how to get a raspberry to start lxde at bootup. But I'm not sure if it will log in automatically, considering I have a password on my 'pi' user. Any of you guys know?

I'm running raspbian, however, I am **not** using the default `lightdm`. I need the GUI to start at boot because it's running a google printer service, and (afaik) chromium needs to start for the printer to go online.

Comment: I would not follow those instructions if `cat /etc/issue` indicates you are using Raspbian 8, which is the latest image.

Comment: @goldilocks it seems I'm running Raspbian 7

Comment: Since you're not running it stock and are instead using an alternative display manager (which is what controls the GUI login), your question is not really very pi specific and would be better off on our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'd say that customization is rather inherent in all Linux boxes. And it is running a raspberry pi specific OS. But sure, I can try another forum.

Comment: There's almost nothing about Raspbian that is actually specific to it, beyond default configurations (meaning, the software is the same, it may just be configured differently than normal Debian).  As a rule of thumb when doing basic technical research, investigate in the *broadest* possible context, not the *narrowest*, and work your way down if necessary.

Comment: E.g., if you are investigating thunderstorms, a meteorologist can probably give you the information you need, but if you are determined to find a meteorologist who specializes in the mesosphere over the Indian ocean, you are going to waste a lot of time in that pursuit.  Likewise if you convince yourself that thunderstorms are specific to Australia and that you will need to travel back and forth from there to do your research.  *You will almost always get better answers more quickly at U&L.*   That is the nature of the beast.

Comment: To illustrate: There are [70 *questions* about SLiM](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=SLiM+is%3Aquestion) at U&L (and most of the first bunch, at least, look like they really are about SLiM, not just "slim").  Here [we have 7](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=SLiM+is%3Aquestion) -- only one of which is actually about SLiM.

Comment: I merely wanted to be sure I got an answer that applies to the Pi.
I honestly never expected this kind of response. To say I feel humbled would be to sugar-coat.

Comment: I apologize if I've been a bit curt.  I don't think it would be nicer to anyone, though, for me to just leave questions like this open here to gather dust (which is what would happen), and/or for other people to waste their time suggesting things only to hear, "Oh, sorry, that won't work -- *I forgot to mention ______*" because **you** have not taken the time to explain your context properly.  That online help is free does not mean it is wise to treat it as a worthless commodity in infinite supply.

Comment: WRT your specific issue, I can't promise you'll find a solution at U&L (or anywhere -- you are into pretty obscure territory) but chances are better.  Software on linux systems is highly modular, meaning intended to function the same way in various contexts.  While there might be pi specific issues here, start out assuming there is not unless you have a concrete reason to believe otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

`raspi-config` should be able to do this for you via the top level option:

```
Choose whether to boot into a desktop environment or the command line
```

There are then choices including:

```
Desktop GUI, automatically logged in as 'pi' user
```

Raspi-config is a shell script in `/usr/bin`, you can look at `do_boot_behaviour_new()` for the details of how to do this "manually" (it depends on whether you are using systemd or the older init system), but there is no normally no need to do so.

If you're not using `lightdm` but you are using Raspbian 8 (jessie), I think `raspi-config` will still work, depending on what's been done with regard to your choosen DM and systemd.  Systemd appears to have it's own mechanism for autologin with `graphical.target`, and presumably this is adapted depending on the DM (but I cannot say for sure).

If you're using Raspbian 7, however, `raspi-config` will re-enable `lightdm` here, which you don't want.  In this case it is also using a hardcoded mechanism specific to lightdm.  You will need to instead configure whatever DM it is you are using, since that's what controls this.

Comment: Looks like raspi-config only works with lightdm, and I'm currently testing slim. Either way, I need to know as much as possible of what's going on under this hood, for educational purposes. But I'll look into the boot_behaviour thingy.

Comment: I.e., your question is really "How do I enable autologin w/ SLiM?" https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SLiM#Enable_Autologin

Comment: Quite possibly. If that is all there is to get the system to autologin. If slim.conf has complete control, then that's all that I'm after.
But looking at the instructions from eLinux.org, I get the feeling that there's other things playing into this. Also, does Slim always grab the boot, when Slim is installed? Can't a system have Slim installed, but boot to command line?

Comment: What's the purpose in logging in on the command line then starting a DM, particularly if you are only using one DE?  It would probably be simpler for you to just use the command line autologin then have the pi user automatically `startx` via a login script, and skip SLiM completely.